# Unable to access website hosted on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, hosting

I am hosting my website on AWS EC2 Instance, everything was working fine till this morning. I am unable to reach my website in browser using both elastic IP as well as site domain name i.e http://www.evogame.gq/ . But when I connect to EC2 using SSH it connects, I don't know the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing listening on the web server port(s):

```
nmap -PN www.evogame.gq
... snip ...
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
20/tcp   closed ftp-data
21/tcp   closed ftp
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3306/tcp open   mysql
```

Note that "closed" means there is access to that port, but that nothing is listening on it.

So, make sure the web server is running.